# What is a good Business Rule Engine(BRE) for .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, business-rules

Do you know of a good business rule engine for .Net? I know Drools.Net is one but it seems to me that its inactive. There is also NXBRE but seems to me that it is not solid enough. Does any body here have a good one? Please suggest.

Update 1,

I did a research based on the suggestions below. Seems to me that Windows Workflow Foundation is enough to what I wanted to do. Since I'm using WCF it would be a good match. But I'm still haven't decided yet.

Best regards,

Comment: I would prefer something that uses the "Rete Algorithm".

Comment: Have you seen http://rule.codeeffects.com ? I don't think they use the Rete, though.

Comment: As a note, it's usually pays off by re-evaluating your real need for rete. You'd widen the range of choices of BRMs if you really don't need rete and only require it because you think you might need it in the future. Most of mid-sized clients we have don't use/need rete algorithm. In most cases it's MUCH faster and safer if you evaluate two - three rules in a row based on the outcome of a previous rule  instead of letting the engine decide how to evaluate a large rule set.

Comment: @Kizz Right. I thought that I might need rete in the future. But at this point, you are correct. I will consider using BRM's that is not using rete algorithm. Thank you. I'm testing some of it now like Simon mentioned above.

Comment: Have a check at http://www.flexrule.com it supports Rete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the rules engine that is part of the [Windows Workflow Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480193.aspx).

- It is a forward chaining rule engine only
- It is free
- You can enable rule execution tracing

etc.

Comment: Update: Acumen is no longer in business.

Answer (score 1):

I have used CSLA.net its free, but he writes a book that might help you understand whats going on

http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/

Comment: CSLA.NET is not a rules engine, AFAIU

Answer (score 1):

Check out Biztalk's BRE.  If your willing to invest a small amount of money into the solution then Biztalk is an option.

http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/business-rule-framework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

IBM ILOG Jrules uses Rete Algorithm and it has .net support too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Common Knowledge @ [Object Connections](http://www.objectconnections.com). I have used the Delphi SDK but they also have a .NET SDK. The visual editor is very good. One issue is a lack of autocompletion but they have just tweeted that it is about to be added.